# Android - Graphview resetData

Tags: android, android-graphview

For a project i have to measure the sound level. 
My app works perfectly and it draws a graph of the sound level i measure. 
But for some reason i can't reset my data of grapview.

I can't put all my code here because of restrictions in stackoverflow.

#### defining the graph

I define the graph onCreate

```
GraphView graph = (GraphView) findViewById(R.id.graph);
    // data
    series = new LineGraphSeries<DataPoint>();
    graph.addSeries(series);
    series.setThickness(2);
    // customize a little bit viewport
    Viewport viewport = graph.getViewport();
    viewport.setYAxisBoundsManual(true);
    viewport.setXAxisBoundsManual(true);
    viewport.setMinY(0);
    viewport.setMaxY(25000);
    viewport.setMinX(0);
    viewport.setMaxX(5000);
    viewport.setScrollable(true);
        final LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(new DataPoint[] {
            new DataPoint(0, 0)
    });
    graph.addSeries(series);
```

#### addEntry

i use this to add a new datapoint in my series:

```
private void addEntry(int a, int b) {
    series.appendData(new DataPoint(a, b), true, 50000);
}
```

#### resetData

a special button to reset the data in the series (later i will replace that button with something else)

```
buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        series.resetData(new DataPoint[] {});
    }
});
```

I also tried

```
buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        series.resetData(new DataPoint[] {new DataPoint(0, 0)});
    }
});
```

#### error

But for some reason i even after pressing the button multiple times i still get the 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: new x-value must be greater then the last value. x-values has to be ordered in ASC.' error

```
'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: new x-value must be greater then the last value. x-values has to be ordered in ASC.'
```

Comment: Have you tired putting a datapoint in the array initializer? like: series.resetData(new DataPoint[] {new DataPoint(0, 0)});

Comment: yes i tried that